# Rails & Postgres: Join tables on an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

Conceptually what I am trying to do is to be able to say: product a is available in 5 colors, which will be an array of color ids. These color ids are the keys that link to a colors table that holds color related data such as hex representations, color images, and so on. Finally, I want to join the colors table with the products table so that I can pull over color related data.

In my current setup, I have two tables: `products` and `colors`. In my `products` table I have a column (`color_ids`) that holds an array of integers. This array holds the ids of the `colors` in the `colors` table. To join the two in Rails, I created a custom SQL string that is in the `Product` class e.g.:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :colors

  def self.custom_query   
    "SELECT * FROM products JOIN colors on colors.id = ANY(products.color_ids)
    WHERE products.name = 'Some Product'"
  end

end
```

I tried using associations (`includes(:colors)`) but that doesn't seem to work since the primary id is an array of ids.

Is there a more elegant / Rails way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use simple [has_and_belongs_to_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) association. Don't store your reference ids in an array, just because PostgreSQL kind of allows you to do so, it's not how relations should be implemented in relational databases.

```
# new migration
create_table :colors_products do |t|
  t.references :color, foreign_key: true
  t.references :product, foreign_key: true
end
add_index :colors_products, [:color_id, :product_id], unique: true


class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colors
end

class Color < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

All of the ActiveRecord methods will work then.

Why shouldn't you have relations made with arrays (unless you **really** know what you're doing):

1. You cannot use Foreign keys. You will be able to have a color_id in your array that is no longer in the database.
2. If you delete a color, your database cannot take care of automatically clearing its id for all products.
3. ActiveRecord (and most ORM) will simply not work and you will need huge amount of workarounds.

Comment: This issue with your answer (not really an issue) is that Rails will need to open a connection to the database every time I want to access color information. I am looking to optimize the db hits so Rails only opens a connection once to retrieve all the data that is needed. Also, why shouldn't relations be implemented the way I have it out of curiosity? My way there is only one row for each color. The other way would need one additional row for each new color, then if you add sizes, it gets exponentially bigger.

Comment: You can use eager loading by calling `includes` in order to avoid N+1 queries. I'll add the issues in the original answer.

Comment: That's what I originally tried doing e.g. Product.includes(:colors) but because the color_ids are in an array in the products table I get an error. If you can figure a way around that without changing the array type then that would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: `includes` is a really complex method that decides whether it should be doing eager loading by left joins are additional queries. I strongly recommend you to turn around before it's too late, or you'll be fighting a really uphill battle against ActiveRecord :( The includes issue will be one of many, but of course you can try.

Comment: Haha I agree. I was doing it more for curiosity than anything else. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def colors   
    Color.where(id: color_ids)
  end
end

class Color < ApplicationRecord
  def products   
    Product.where('? = Any (category_ids)', id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view named like:

```
CREATE VIEW product_colors(id, product_id, name, hex, image) AS

SELECT
  p.id as product_id,
  c.name,
  c.hex,
  c.image
FROM
  (
  SELECT
      id,
      unnest(color_ids) as color_id
    FROM
      products
  ) as p
  INNER JOIN colors c
    ON c.id = p.color_id;
```

And then add model `ProductColor` with

```rb
def readonly?
 true
end
```

And you can treat this view as a child model. `Products.includes(:product_colors)`